# JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync()) returning a buffer - string of numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a simple Node.js to pull information from a valid jsonfile (checked with JSLint), but the code i'm using doesn't return the expected value:

```
        squadJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./squads/squad' + whichSquad + '.json'));
```

and it returns:

```
{ type: 'Buffer', data: 
[ 123,
 10,
 32,
 32,
 34,
 97,
 99,
 ... 548 more items ] }
```

Any reason as to why this happens?

Comment: What's the expected value?

Comment: No. `JSON.parse` does never return a buffer.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync()` returns a Buffer if you don't specify an encoding.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

So, tell `fs.readFileSync()` what encoding to use:

```
squadJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./squads/squad' + whichSquad + '.json', 'utf8'));
```

Comment: Yup! Passing a value to the 2nd parameter will do the trick like so:
`fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.json', 'utf8')`. **Thank you** so much.

Answer (score 12):

The "why" has been [answered by Sidney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48818444/1541563), but a better "what to do" would be to use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require), which supports [parsing valid JSON files](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) synchronously and returning the result as an object:

```
squadJSON = require('./squads/squad' + whichSquad + '.json');
```

or even nicer, using an ES6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
squadJSON = require(`./squads/squad${whichSquad}.json`);
```

One notable difference using `require()` is that it resolves relative paths from [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname), which is the directory path of the current module, whereas [`fs` methods resolve relative paths](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths) using [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), or "current working directory". It is the directory within a shell session from which the main module of the program is executed by node.

Hopefully the examples below demonstrate how their relative path resolution differs:

To make `require(...)` behave like `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(..., 'utf8'))`:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

function readFileSyncJson (path) {
  return require(resolve(process.cwd(), path));
}
```

And to make `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(..., 'utf8'))` behave like `require(...)`:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

function requireJson (path) {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(resolve(__dirname, path), 'utf8'));
}
```

Comment: Very true, `require` is much more convenient for reading JSON files. Also, `require` always resolves relative to the file it's called in, whereas I believe `fs.readFileSync` resolves based the current working directory (unless you specifically resolve using `__dirname`).

Comment: Sorry, but it returns the exact same thing for me, whether i use Require or specify the encoding... @sidney

Comment: @ConradScherb that can often be the case, which means that the module `require()` is called from is in the same directory as (or _is_) the file you invoked using `node`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so in that case what would be the solution to that?

Comment: @ConradScherb I added examples to hopefully clarify their differences. There's no problem in the first place, the information is just there to make you aware of nuances.