# Discord Bot Issue - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id') at /index.js:144:31. My index.js code is below:

```
if(interaction.customId == 'generateCode') {

        // defer
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

        // already generated?
        data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./system/index.json`));
*This is row 144, user.id is the issue*
        if(data.filter(t => t.id == interaction.user.id)[0]) {
            embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('DARK_BLUE')
                .setAuthor({ name: interaction.user.tag, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
                .setDescription("`"+data.filter(t => t.id == interaction.user.id)[0].code+"`")
            await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that your user object is null. It looks like the `data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync())` is not pulling in the file.

Based on this: [JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync()) returning a buffer - string of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818415/json-parsefs-readfilesync-returning-a-buffer-string-of-numbers) readFileSync returns a buffer if you don't add an encoding.

```
data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./system/index.json`, 'utf8'))
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! Any potential fix?

Comment: @MikeHigh, I've updated my answer for you

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have done the trick. I'm using a server hosting service (PebbleHost) and that is where i've uploaded my files. The only thing I can think is that for whatever reason the pull request is not finding the correct folder path. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MikeHigh are you able to console log the results of data? That's defiantly a possibility.